# How does wildfly elytron authentication work

Tags: authentication, ldap, wildfly, elytron

**problem authentication with elytron wildfly ==>**
my configuration of **LEGACY** authentication ldap with the old versions of wildfy is worked good and authenticated only superuser part of specific group

after switching to **wildfly 26** which supports elytron, I am facing authentication problems, the problem that I have to authenticate only for a SUPERUSER belonging to a group and not all users
but the configuration I made takes and accesses all users and I don't

Comment: @james-r-perkins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `identity-mapping` configuration, I think you'll want to add the `filter-name` attribute and set it to `"(&amp;(sAMAccountName={0})(memberOf=CN=tfff wildfly Admins,CN=Users,dc=com,dc=global))"`.

Then, in the `attribute-mapping` configuration, the `filter` can be set to `"(&amp;(objectClass=group)(member={1}))"`.

Comment: hi bro thanks for your help is worker for me..if you have any idea how do i integrate elytron ldap with RBAC, because i want to limit x group of to enter as superuser but only as monitor

Comment: Perhaps this might help:

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/6603181